# Change href when user clicks link

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Ok So im trying to add an id to a link example:

```
<a href="http://google.com/stats.php?go=normal">normal</a>  
<a href="http://google.com/stats.php?go=normalmedium">normal medium</a> 
<a href="http://google.com/stats.php?go=normalmediumhigh">normal medium high</a> 
<a href="http://google.com/stats.php?go=normalhigh">normal high</a> 
<a href="http://google.com/stats.php?go=superhigh">super high</a>
```

by default the links are like this but if they click on let say a button or link like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeIt('bnone9099');>burner one</a> 
<a href="#" onclick="changeIt('bnone9034');>burner two</a> 
<a href="#" onclick="changeIt('bnone9098');>burner three</a>
```

when they click on one of the links it should add an id like this example if they click "burner one" :

```
<a href="http://google.com/stats.php?go=normal&id=bnone9099">normal</a>  
<a href="http://google.com/stats.php?go=normalmedium&id=bnone9099">normal medium</a> 
<a href="http://google.com/stats.php?go=normalmediumhigh&id=bnone9099">normal medium high</a> 
<a href="http://google.com/stats.php?go=normalhigh&id=bnone9099">normal high</a> 
<a href="http://google.com/stats.php?go=superhigh&id=bnone9099">super high</a>
```

and so on and if they click

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeIt('back');>default</a>
```

it should change the links back to normal like this

```
<a href="http://google.com/stats.php?go=normal">normal</a>  
<a href="http://google.com/stats.php?go=normalmedium">normal medium</a> 
<a href="http://google.com/stats.php?go=normalmediumhigh">normal medium high</a> 
<a href="http://google.com/stats.php?go=normalhigh">normal high</a> 
<a href="http://google.com/stats.php?go=superhigh">super high</a>
```

i hope this example is not too complicated! thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function changer(){
   var changedArr = [];
   this.changeIt = function($this, str ){

     if(str!="back"){
         $this = document.getElementById($this);
         $this.href = $this.href+"&id="+str;
         changedArr.push( $this );
     }else{
         for( var i=0, len=changedArr.length;i<len;i++){
           var lastInd = changedArr[i].href.lastIndexOf("&");
           changedArr[i].href = changedArr[i].href.substr(0,lastInd);
         }
     }
  };

}

var chHandler = new changer();
```

and html...

```
<a id="link1" href="http://google.com/stats.php?go=normal">normal</a>  
<a id="link2" href="http://google.com/stats.php?go=normalmedium">normal medium</a> 
<a id="link3" href="http://google.com/stats.php?go=normalmediumhigh">normal medium high</a> 
<a id="link4" href="http://google.com/stats.php?go=normalhigh">normal high</a> 
<a id="link5" href="http://google.com/stats.php?go=superhigh">super high</a>
```

and...

```
<a href="#" onclick="chHandler.changeIt('link1','bnone9099');">burner one</a> 
<a href="#" onclick="chHandler.changeIt('link2','bnone9034');">burner two</a> 
<a href="#" onclick="chHandler.changeIt('link3','bnone9098');">burner three</a>

<a href="#" onclick="chHandler.changeIt('dummy','back');">BACK</a>
```

Explanation of the above code.
We are creating a new object of "changer()", in the changeIt class, we are passing two arguments - the first is the id of the link who's id is to be edited, and the second one is the value's/id's data.

we are keeping the changed links into an array called changedArr, and when back is clicked (triggered because it sents 'back' as the second argument), we are doing a for-loop in the changedArr, and remove everything that follows the last occurance of &.... (which is always in this situation the id arg)

You can see a working example here,
http://jsfiddle.net/H2YHw/

Comment: thankyou exactly what i was looking for thanks for taking the time on coding this.! :)

Comment: Hello, you can also try this one 

http://jsfiddle.net/H2YHw/1/

I think I made a mistake on the code I posted above, but this link works 100% as it should ;)

Comment: i don't really see the java adding the sub id's ?

Comment: NVM it was a mistake on my part thanks again now it works perfectly! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar in the past.
It was in PHP, but the idea is very much the same. I use it quite frequently especially when dealing with page numbers, when I add `&p=3` to link to specific page. I just keep it in my utility box. Anyway, this is how I tackled it.

1. You need to check if your url has already **id** parameter.
2. If it does then change it, if it doesn't simply add one.

To filter parameters you can write a method that will take two strings one with parameter **id** and one with **value**. It has to do following.

1. `split` `http://google.com/stats.php?go=superhigh&id=333231` via **?** character to get the second part (parameters) of the url.
2. `split` second part of the url - `array[1]` by **&** - this will give you an array of all parameters with their values. Note: check if there it contains & if it doesn't then move to step 3.
3. For loop through every one of them and `split` it by **=** - `array[0]` is your parameter and `array[1]` is the value. If your parameter matches the parameter needed update it with new value and break. If it doesn't then add a new set of parameter/values to the end of the url.

I hope that makes sense.

Reference:
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html#split

Answer (score 1):

Lets make use of jquery's .data() funciton

```
function changeIt(arg){
    // I highly recommend you add something to control the target 'a' tags
    // 'the_link_undercontrol' is merely my assumption
    $('a.the_link_undercontrol').each(function(){
        var $t = $(this);
        if(arg == 'back'){
            if($t.data('originalLnk')){
                $t.attr('href', $t.data('originalLnk'))
            }
        } else {
            var href = $t.attr('href');
            if(href.indexOf('?') != -1){
                // you need to check if 'id' is the only parameter!!
                // and for best practice, get your param properly encoded
                $t.attr('href', href + '?id=' + encodeURIComponent(arg);
            } else {
                $t.attr('href', href + '&id=' + encodeURIComponent(arg);
            }
            $t.data('orginalLnk', href);
        }
    }
}
```